# How does Ubuntu Touch behave?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7, nexus-4

How does Ubuntu Touch behave with an external screen and bluetooth mouse/keyboard?

I was considering a nexus 7 with ubuntu installed to do some coding and I am not shure if that will work. All I need is gcc and vim. It seems like a brilliant way to ditch my laptop and just carry a tablet between home and work. I have tried Google and watching videos on YouTube but can't get a sense of what is possible or practical. I would like to now if the device mirrors the screen and which bluetooth devices are recommended. Ideally I would just use a nexus 4 with a dock at work and a dock at home and some sort of yet to be invented/released empty laptop for use on the go. Apologies if I have missed this information elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you connect an external screen, your device's screen will become a touch pad to interact with the mouse pointer at the external screen. If you click to an area, where a keyboard is needed, the on screen keyboard will automatically pop up on the device's screen, so that the upper half if screen will remain as touch pad.

Connecting a bluetooth mouse will force your device into convergenced mode, even if there is no external screen. Connecting a keyboard will prevent, that the onnscreen keyboard pops up.
You can use any type of bluetooth mouse or keyboard, which supports the normal bluetooth standard of your device. I recommend to use english keyboard layout because others are not supported, yet.